# How to call php function to get updated data from MYSQL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I have a number in the MYSQL table which is displayed on the screen using the function:

```
function getWinNumber($db) {

    $user = getProfileInfoFor($_SESSION['id'], $db); 

    $winNumber = $user->number;

    return $winNumber;
}
```

Then after some user actions that value changes in the DB and I want to update it in front-end when they close a foundation modal:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '#ex6-4', function () {

        $('.number').html("<?php echo getWinNumber($db);?>");

    });
```

The problem is that even though the code works, and I can clearly see in the DB that the value has changed before I close the modal, the value being pulled is still the old one. Why is that?

If I put anything else in there like:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '#ex6-4', function () {

        $('.number').html("test");

    });
```

it  works. It updates when I close the modal.

Comment: PHP is processed server-side, so before the JavaScript ever goes to the client. You need AJAX. Search for a tutorial on that and go from there.

Comment: Are you sure that the value in the database changes? Where is your code for updating the database?

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks man. Idk what was I thinking. It worked perfectly with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with AJAX like this and it worked:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '#ex6-4', function () {

         $.ajax({ url: 'include/update.php',
             data: {action: 'update'},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {

                      $('.encrypted').html(output);
                  }
        });  
    });
```

and for the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {

    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == 'update') {

        echo getWinNumber($db);
    }
}
```